# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in c# how to check for null value?

Tags: c#

I am getting nullrefernce exception after running c# code at this line

```
  var data = info.details.Split('|');
```

c# code:

```
 public studentinfo SaveData(studentinfo info)
        {
            bool returnBool=false;
            SqlConnection con;

                var data = info.details.Split('|');


                var response = new studentinfo
                {
                    ID = data[0],
                    Name = data[1],
                    Project = data[2],
                    Result = data[3]
                };


            con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Myproject.Properties.Settings.MyConnection"].ConnectionString);

            string sqlStr = "INSERT INTO Result (ID,Name,Project,Result) values('" + data[0] + "', '" + data[1] + "', '" + data[2] + "', '" + data[3] + "')";
            SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, con);

             try
            {
                con.Open();
                if (dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
                {
                    returnBool = true;
                }

                if (!data.Equals(null))
                {
                    returnBool = true;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
               returnBool= false;
            }
             con.Close();
             return response;

        }
```

I tried to implement:

```
if (!data.Equals(null))
            {
                returnBool = true;
            }
```

but even then its giving the same object reference exception, Please help me to resolve it. 
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see if `info` or `info.details` is null?

Comment: That code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practially begging to get hacked.

Comment: You are creating it as a var, why not as the data type it is?

Comment: Either `info` is null or `info.details` is null, I'd check those.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg Why does it even matter? `var` is not a type itself. Type of `data` will be whatever `details.Split('|');` returns.

Comment: It would be so much easier for us to see what it exactly returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
if(data != null)
{

}
```

Or

```
if(object.ReferenceEquals(data,null))
{

}
```

Probably as @zigdawgydawg pointed out exception will not be in checking `data` because `string.Split` will never return `null`. So, you need to avoid null parameter.

```
if(info==null || info.details == null)
{
    return null;//Or throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Comment: Thanks now its not giving exception.

Answer (score 2):

The Null reference exception is because either `info` or `info.details` is null.  You'll need to check for nulls before you do a `Split`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for null before you try the string split

```
if (info == null)
{
    // do not attempt to split details, maybe throw something here
}
```

However, you may want to look at how that `SaveData(studentinfo info)` is being called, and under what circumstances would it be passed a null `studentinfo` object.